# Inserting the table metadata last modified information as a column in an existing table

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table called apps and I replace this by using dataprep workflows on a weekly basis. I need to add a column to apps table which shows the last modified date for the table. I can use Information_schema to get this information but I am not sure how I can add the last modified date into my existing table apps.

I tried Information_schema to get the table name and last modified date but need to include this date as last_modified into my existing table in the code below. I need to insert a column with the last modified date in the table

```
SELECT *
FROM 
`xxx.xxx.Apps`
LIMIT 10


SELECT *, DATE(TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(last_modified_time)) AS 
last_modified_date
FROM 
`xxx.xxx.Apps`
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Using public dataset as an example:

```sql
DECLARE last_modified_time DATE DEFAULT 
  (SELECT DATE(TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(last_modified_time)) FROM `bigquery-public-data.crypto_bitcoin.__TABLES__` 
   WHERE table_id = 'blocks');

SELECT *, last_modified_time
FROM `bigquery-public-data.crypto_bitcoin.blocks` LIMIT 1
```

or, with single statement using subquery

```sql
WITH last_modified_time as 
  (SELECT DATE(TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(last_modified_time)) FROM `bigquery-public-data.crypto_bitcoin.__TABLES__` 
   WHERE table_id = 'blocks')
SELECT *, (SELECT * FROM last_modified_time)
FROM `bigquery-public-data.crypto_bitcoin.blocks` LIMIT 1
```